# Removing even length strings but returning only one of them

Tags: python, list, return

```py
def remove_even_length(thisList):
    for i in range(0,len(thisList)):
        splittoString = thisList[i].split(' ')
        
        for word in splittoString:
            if not len(word)%2 ==0:
                print(word)
```

This code prints what I want.

```py
def remove_even_length(thisList):
    for i in range(0,len(thisList)):
        splittoString = thisList[i].split(' ')
        
        for word in splittoString:
            if not len(word)%2 ==0:
                return(word)
```

But does only return first odd number not the rest

I used this as a example List

```py
['even', 'odd', 'ev', 'o']
```

Why can't I get whole word as a return but only first odd number? How can I have it return me every odd word?

## My Update1:

I did this this to solve the problem but this one doesn't solve a single value list like : **['deletion']**

```py
def remove_even_length(thisList):
    for i in range(0,len(thisList)-1):
        ' '.join(thisList)
        print(thisList)
        for word in thisList:
            if len(word)%2 ==0:
                thisList.remove(word)

    return thisList
```

## Solution :

```py
def remove_even_length(thislist):
    for i in [i for i in thislist if len(i)%2==0]:
        thislist.remove(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you call return in a function, the function exits.

Change that to this

```
def remove_even_length(thisList):
    array = []
    for i in range(0,len(thisList)):
        splittoString = thisList[i].split(' ')

        for word in splittoString:
            if not len(word)%2 ==0:
                array.append(word)

    return array
```

### Update:

To change **thisList** and not create a new list use this

```
thisList = ["hello", "world", "abcd"]
thisList = remove_even_length(thisList)
```

### Update 2

This will modify thisList instead of creating a new list

```
def remove_even_length(thisList):
    for i in range(0,len(thisList)):
        splittoString = thisList[i].split(' ')

        for word in splittoString:
            if len(word)%2 ==0:
                thisList.remove(word)

    #uncomment next line if you want to return the list from this function
    #return thisList
```

Comment: How can I do this by changing thisList not by creating new array?

Comment: You can't change thisList directly from the function. I have updated the answer. See that. And also, as the name suggests **remove_even_length** isn't the logic wrong? Did you mean **remove_odd**?

Comment: I should be updating thisList by removing all the even words.

And he says update, I should be using thisList in the function and return thisList at the end.

Comment: Ohh sorry.. i got that wrong.. and the code should now fulfill your needs

Comment: I think I couldn't explain. Instead of return array I need to return thisList. Its gonna take a list and remove even words and return same list. Not a new list created in the function.

Comment: Check if it works now

Comment: I used your code and increased it in the  **My Update1:**  section. Can you check??

Comment: Seems like you got the solution yourself. Good luck. Keep going

Answer (score 0):

Your return statement is called the first time you get a match.

Put all your matches in a list and then return the list once all the words have been processed.

Comment: How can I do this by changing thisList not by creating new array?